# Hide image when click outside of image in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, image, hide

When my WPF application loads, an image is shown in center. 
how can i handle mouse click outside of image. when user clicks outside of image it hide.
My code is in c#.

Comment: please paste your code

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add a handler to the top level control, eg. `Grid`, `Window`, etc. In that handler, you can check whether the control that was clicked on was the `Image` and if it wasn't, then you could hide it:

The XAML:

```
<Grid PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
    ...
    <Image Name="TheImage" Source="/WpfApplication2;component/Images/Add_16.png" />
    ...
</Grid>
```

The code behind:

```
private void Grid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource != TheImage)
    {
        TheImage.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

While this fulfils your requirements, it should be noted that once hidden, the `Image` will no longer be 'clickable'.

Answer (score 1):

just put the code `MyImage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;` in whichever event you want to capture.

for eg:

```
private void MyButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyImage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
}


private void MyTextbox_PreviewMouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MyImage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

private void MyWindow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MyImage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

where `MyImage` is the name of image, `MyTextbox` is the name of textbox, `MyButton` is the name of Button and `MyWindow` is the name of Main Window

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write

`YourImageName.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;`

Write this code to any of the control  i.e. `TextBox` or `Button`.

Comment: i want know how can i handle mouse click outside of image.

Comment: that's what i told you. you just drag one button and have its event handler and write this code on button click.

Comment: i want hide image when user click any position of form not only on button or textbox

Comment: @NeelBhasin, you *didn't* tell the user how to handle a mouse `Click` outside of an `Image`. Your answer was barely a comment and didn't answer the question at all. Please think carefully before you answer questions because although I won't down vote this, there are plenty of users that would. Also, if you're not helping the user to solve their problem, then what's the point of answering?

Comment: @Sheridan if you read the question , he has mentioned `when user clicks a button or textbox outside of image` this statement. for that i have provided this answer only.

Comment: @NeelBhasin, I simply tried to give you some advice on how to provide good, useful answers. If you decide to ignore that, that's completely up to you.

Comment: @Sheridan i am not ignoring that actually. i have only justified the reason for providing this answer

Answer (score 0):

first click on the form to select it. then go to the event's section (near property section) and double-click the click event to make a function call when a form is clicked. in the code compare the sender object with the `IsEqual(obj)` method and see the sender is same image or it's not. if not hide it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the click event of Application current window , and inside that event you can check if the mouse position is within that image or outside of that image , on basis of this you can set your image visibility condition you prefer .

Code sample example :

```
//registering event
Application.Curent.mainWindow.MouseRightButtonDown += MainWindow_MouseRightButtonDown;

//event implementation
void MouseRightButtonDown(object sender , MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
//here you can check the ui element for image control using sender

//below will let you know the position of Click 
e.GetPosition(// pass the ui element here)
}
```

> Note : The above code shown is at app level click handling . If you
>   dont want at app level you can take the parent xaml within which the
>   image is present and do the same